# Dictionary makes value for all keys equal to most recent key/value addition

Tags: ms-access, vba, dictionary, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to add some items to a dictionary object (database ID and value pair) to let the user confirm their selections before they commit. I have this following code section which add an item to the dictionary. After the add I loop through the Dictionary.Keys and print each key/value to a listbox for the user to see. My dictionary object is a public variable on my form and is set in the Form_Load event.

```
Dim PickListID As Integer
If txtPercentOfStream <> "" Then
    PickListID = cboCoalTypes
    If Not CoalsInStreamDic.Exists(PickListID) Then
        CoalsInStreamDic.Add PickListID, txtPercentOfStream
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The weird thing is that whenever I add a new key/value pair the value for the new key becomes the value for all existing keys in addition to the new key.

I run this little block before and after interacting with the dictionary

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In CoalsInStreamDic.Keys
    Debug.Print key & "::" & CoalsInStreamDic.item(key)
Next key
Debug.Print
```

i.e. user clicks the button and the *first* think that happens is this above block to confirm the old keys have their original values, but they don't. They have already been replaced with the "new value". Running the block afterwards confirms this.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not adding the text of the TextBox, but rather the TextBox instead

If you change your code to the following it should work

```
If txtPercentOfStream <> "" Then
    Dim PickListID As Integer, PercentOfStream As Integer
    PercentOfStream = txtPercentOfStream
    PickListID = cboCoalTypes
    If Not CoalsInStreamDic.Exists(PickListID) Then
        CoalsInStreamDic.Add PickListID, PercentOfStream
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Ah it makes perfect sense! The only issue is using `txtPercentOfStream.Text` gives this error "You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus." So I did a `Dim PercentOfStream As Integer` then `PercentOfStream = txtPercentOfStream` and added `PercentOfStream` to my dictionary.

Comment: The other way to do it is to call `txtPercentOfStream.Value` instead. The `.Text` property is frustrating to use and calling it is almost never doable.

Comment: Sorry just saw these comments now, I'm glad you sorted out your problem, and I'll update my answer with your comments

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I just made one more correction: the initial `if` was comparing an integer to a string, I changed the condition to look at the textbox then assign the textbox to the integer `PercentOfStream`